# CNN - Do we need to manually preprocess training images?

Tags: tensorflow, image-processing, conv-neural-network, tf.keras, training-data

Am a complete noob and I just want to ask, do we need to preprocess images (like manually) before feeding the image into CNN for training? I've read that CNN already has some filtering techniques to extract features and such. I'm thinking what if all the train images are binary images or even just edges (teaching the model for shapes), is it advisable or I'll just feed grayscale images? Additionally, if the answer is yes, may I know what kind of preparation is done normally or what you would use?

I am aware of the other preprocessing techniques by Keras, such as the VGG16, but I would like something simple and manual.

Answer (score 0):

The preprocessing functions of Keras only preprocess the input according to the state-of-the-art models requirements, e.g., changing the data format etc. May be, what you are talking about is *hand-engineered features*, which is not simple. And I think, it's not advisable because CNN does a better job. But it may also depend on what you actually want to do.

Comment: Yeah exactly. So keras provides these preprocessing functions that only transform images into like easily readable formats. I am confused as to where image preprocessing (the one you mentioned, hand-engineered feature extraction) comes into play. I imagined that, since I've trained my model using the transformed format train images, I would also do the exact same thing with the test images when trying to predict its class.

Comment: And, correct me if I'm wrong, I should not feed a binary image into the model when predicting its class. I can only use them for masking to remove unnecessary noise/background?

Comment: May be have a look at this one as an example: https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-020-77264-y
They have compared hand-engineered features and CNNs.